# On starting ember server embercli throws some errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
error is not defined
ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/dexter/weaponx/lance/learnerapp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:204:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:173:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:819:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:320:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:78:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:170:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:470:12)
```

**Ember details**

```
version: 1.13.13
node: 5.2.0
npm: 2.14.10
os: linux x64
```

**Watchman details**

```
4.1.0
```

The problem arose after the installation of watchman from the guide issued by facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Only just started tinkering with Ember and encountered the same error, with the same version of Watchman, a more experienced user might be able to point us in the direction of a proper fix but in the meantime, in my case on Ubuntu it seems Watchman required an increase in `max_user_watches`.

See the **Linux inotify Limits** section here https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html and in the **Problems** section here https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli#problems the following `Ubuntu / Debian` command is suggested:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Although there seems to be some concern that *524288* could be too high, *32768* seems to be sufficient.

After setting those values force a Watchman shut-down

```
    $ watchman shutdown-server
```

Then restart the Ember server. Thus far I've not seen the error again.

Comment: What does the max_user_watches entail? Anyway, the commands you published worked fine for me but I am interested in knowing why this error occurred.

Comment: See this link for details on the [inotify API](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/inotify.7.html) I have seen concerns that using a very large number for the `max_user_watches` setting could lead to system resource issues in particular running short of RAM. So far using _32768_ hasn't had a negative impact on my system.

Comment: I removed watchman and set inotify to the limit 524288. No errors so far.